# In the derivation of the integral representation of the beta function, why is the upper limit 1 after changing variables?

Tags: integration, functions, special-functions, beta-function

In the derivation of the beta function the following proof is given:

$\begin{align}
 \Gamma(x)\Gamma(y) &= \int_{u=0}^\infty\ e^{-u} u^{x-1}\,du \cdot\int_{v=0}^\infty\ e^{-v} v^{y-1}\,dv \\[6pt]
 &=\int_{v=0}^\infty\int_{u=0}^\infty\ e^{-u-v} u^{x-1}v^{y-1}\,du \,dv.
\end{align}$

Changing variables by u=zt and v=z(1-t) shows that this is

$\begin{align}
\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y) &= \int_{z=0}^\infty\int_{t=0}^\color{red}{1} e^{-z} (zt)^{x-1}(z(1-t))^{y-1}\big|J(z,t)\big|\,dt \,dz \tag{1}\\[6pt]
 &= \int_{z=0}^\infty\int_{t=0}^\color{red}{1} e^{-z} (zt)^{x-1}(z(1-t))^{y-1}z\,dt \,dz \\[6pt]
 &= \int_{z=0}^\infty e^{-z}z^{x+y-1} \,dz\cdot\int_{t=0}^\color{red}{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt\\
 &=\Gamma(x+y)\,\beta(x,y),
\end{align}$

How was the upper limit of integration calculated after the change of variables.   I thought I understood the Fubini-Tonnelli theorem but I don't understand how the value of 1 was calculated. Why is there no $\frac{1}{z}$ dependence in the upper limit of (1)?

---

In a single dimension its easy to get the limits 0,1 using u=1/x-1 but in the two dimensional plane I'm confused by this substitution.

Comment: If the $t$ integral only ran from $0$ to $1/z$, then the corresponding range of $u$ would only be from 0 to 1.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, ok, so how was the 1 calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see what the limits of integration should be is to write out the inverse transformations.  In this case, we have
$$
u + v = zt + z(1 - t) = z \quad \Rightarrow \quad z = u + v
$$
and
$$\frac{v}{u} = \frac{1 - t}{t} = \frac{1}{t} - 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad t = \frac{1}{v/u + 1}.
$$

We then need to look at the range of values these quantities can take on when $u \in (0, \infty)$ and $v \in (0, \infty)$.  For $z$, $0 < u < \infty$ and $0 < v < \infty$ imply that $0 < z < \infty$.   The values of $t$ are a little more subtle.  The ratio $v/u$ also satisfies $0 < v/u < \infty$;  in the limit $v/u \to 0$, we have $t \to 1$, while in the limit $v/u \to \infty$ we have $t \to 0$.  Since this is an invertible one-to-one coordinate transformation, we can conclude that the limits of integration under this change of variables are $z \in (0, \infty)$ and $t \in (0,1)$.